# Multithreading in C++: loading a large file and performing a function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, sorting, load

I am trying to load a very large text file (about 11 GB in size) and performing a function (which basically breaks the file apart into different sections). I need help to multi-thread the load function into 8 or so threads and during the load function, preform this certain sorting function. (I cant discuss too much about the sort function in detail).

This is all in C++. I have no limit in terms of ram (I have about 60 GB).

Comment: You need more disks, not more cpus.

Comment: You could give more details about the size of the data inside the file and paste some code here. That would help suggest a more appropriate solution for your problem

Comment: As per Hans Passant's comment, the bottleneck is liable to be disk read speed.  Maybe take some of your memory and make a nice big VDISK, or use a fast SSD.  This should help shift the bottleneck back to your CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

You could partition the file into chunks and pass your load function an fseek offset so that your load function can read from the file starting at fseek for some length (and load that into memory) and then operate on that information in the threads (using your secret sorting algorithm). So lets say, take the file size, divide by 8 and calculate fseek offsets or you could take fixed sized chunks and read until you run out of file contents to process (mapping 11gb of HD contents to RAM takes a while and quite a bit of resources so you might want to do this incremenetally). Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Hmmm... we could try that. What we have attempted so far is for the user to input the number of threads and the file is divided into the chunks that way. Your idea seems valid and I can try it. For some reason when we put in 8 threads, only 2 seem to do their job, one claims it did it share (approx 1.2 GB) almost instantaneously and the other 5 just dont do anything. As for our resources, I have nothing to worry about there.

Comment: I'm guessing that there's disk contention because loading 1gb from disk is a lot of pages (1GB / 4KB) so it could take a while for the OS to fullfill those requests. Did you use fseek in your implementation or how did you partition?

Comment: Quite possible this solution will just exhaust the disk read cache, and make the whole thing slower than if it was all in a single thread as each thread sends the disk heads seeking to different physical locations.  There could also be a controller limitation in the number of simultaneous reads allowed.  All a bit hardware dependent tbh.

Comment: Well the OS will order the bio's to read in the most linear order but each one is going to read sequentially anyway to might as well just read in chunks and send them off to processing.

Answer (score 0):

A thread could load into memory in chunks, passing each chunk to its own thread for processing, so that processing can start as early as possible. I don't think that it's a good idea to have multiple threads trying to read from the same file at the same time.

Comment: That makes sense although it's faster to process the file once in memory than it is to load it so the thread may finish before the next one even gets a chance to start. Depends on how heavy the I/O versus sorting is on CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Reserve `FILE_SIZE` memory on the heap, start one thread for reading the file, report back as soon as the reading hits `DATA_READED/NUMBER_OF_DESIRED_THREADS_FOR_PROCESSING` value start a thread that processes that block of readed data from memory, increment the pointer for reading by `DATA_READED/NUMBER_OF_DESIRED_THREADS_FOR_PROCESSING`.Repeat.

Solution 2: Reserve `FILE_SIZE` memory ,create `NUMBER_OF_DESIRED_THREADS_FOR_PROCESSING` and the same number of queues , when reading (again one thread for disk IO), when a chunk is readed distribute the buffer pointers and size of data to process to thread's queues via some locking mechanism. That way all the threads will start working as soon as data is available.

Hans Passant is right if you could use more disks, then you should assign multiple threads to read chunks